TreeView child nodes cannot be set to have no image
I cannot Set the image of child nodes to be empty.
So far i've written this:
        private void InitializeTreeView()
        {
            treeView1 = new TreeView();
            treeView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            treeView1.ShowLines = false;
            treeView1.ShowPlusMinus = false;
            treeView1.ShowRootLines = false;

            ImageList imageList = new ImageList();

            imageList.Images.Add($"Image", Image.FromFile($"IMAGE.PNG"));

            treeView1.ImageList = imageList;

            TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode("Root Node", 0, 0);

            TreeNode childNode1 = new TreeNode("Child Node 1");

            TreeNode childNode2 = new TreeNode("Child Node 2");

            rootNode.Nodes.Add(childNode1);
            rootNode.Nodes.Add(childNode2);

            treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);

            treeView1.ExpandAll();

            this.Controls.Add(treeView1);
        }

i've tried setting the Imageindex to -1 (read somewhere that it makes it empty) that didn't work.
what i'm currently getting is this:
Image
but what i want is the ChildNodes to not have any images.
i tried just making a empty PNG which removes the image. but makes it look really weird.
Image
anyone got a better solution to this?

When you set the ImageList Property of a TreeView, you're suggesting that all nodes are going to show an image. If you set the StateImageList, you're instead suggesting that only nodes with a state set are going to show one. In the first case, some space for an image is always taken into consideration when rendering the Node. In the second case, only in a per-node scenario -- If the default behaviors don't fit your needs, you can simply owner-draw the Control
